# Use pipe line to open a file after it's just created

Tags: linux, pipeline, cat, gedit

I want to achieve something quite simple with pipeline:

step 1 : cat input1 input2 > output

step 2 : gedit output

I can do

```
cat input1 input2 > output | gedit output
```

But I wonder how can I ommit typing the name of output file in this case? So the file created from cat redirect should be the file gedit open.
Thanks!

Comment: A `;` is more appriate than a `|` here; you are not piping anything to gedit.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a `bash` [function](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) for your purpose (perhaps in your `~/.bashrc` if you want to make it permanent), e.g.

```
 editcat() {
   cat $* > output
   gedit output
 }
```

You might want to make that function more fancy, by generating the output file as a temporary file using [mktemp(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mktemp.1.html)

```
 editcat() {
   local editemp=$(mktemp)
   cat $* > $editemp
   gedit $editemp
   rm $editemp
 }
```

But you might consider just using [less(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
gedit <(cat file1 file2)
```

or

```
cat input1 input2 | gedit
```

Comment: It does not work, with en error message like `could not open the file "/proc/self/fd/11", not a regular file`